# Why Nesting .map method in Ruby behaves strange for my case?

Tags: ruby, dictionary, methods, nested

Maybe it's not common to do like this, but anyway. I'm curious why it's not working.
I encountered with a strange behavior which I don't fully understand.

```
string = "sdsdasda asdas asdas"
words = string.split

words.map! do |word|
    word.split(//).map! do |character|
        character.upcase #or any other operations that change character
    end.join
end

p words.join(" ")
```

If I instead of odd "end.join" construction this

```
    end
    word.join
end
```

I get an error, because |word| remains the same (string and not upcase), despite of using

```
.map!
```

with an exclamation point.
So basically my question is why map! won't change the word.

Comment: Leave out the bang for the inner map block. Map is taking the response of each block invocation. There is no need to modify *word* in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.map!` is being called on the result of `.split(//)`. It's modifying the resulting array, not the original `word`

You can think of the result of `.split(//)` being placed in a new variable:

```
characters = word.split(//)
characters.map! do |character|
  character.upcase
end

return characters.join
# `word` is not modified
```

Answer (score 0):

**The last line of code in your block determines the value returned to the previous loop.**

By adding `.join` to the `end` you are essentially saying that you want to return the result of that block of code to the previous `map!` call. But when you add an additional line afterwards to explicitly do `word.join`then you are saying you want to return the result of `word.join` to the previous `map!` call. As Leny Sirivong pointed out, that `word` is still lowercase (you can confirm by printing out `word` right there).

Consider this alternate syntax to make it clearer:

```
string = "sdsdasda asdas asdas"
words = string.split

words.map! do |word|
    result = word.split(//).map! {|character|character.upcase }.join
    p "word: " + word
    p "result: " + result
end

p words.join(" ")
```

You will see here that it actually works because I'm assigning the result of the loop to a new variable `result`. Then, `result` is passed back to the original `map!` call instead of `word`.

```
"word: sdsdasda"
"result: SDSDASDA"
"word: asdas"
"result: ASDAS"
"word: asdas"
"result: ASDAS"
```

If you run this you will see in this case that the end result prints `["result: SDSDASDA", "result: ASDAS", "result: ASDAS"]`. That is because the last line of my loop is `p "result: " + result`.